# Use moment.js as date and time picker from calendar

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I like to use javascript and html for client side date picking of future or past.
does `moment.js` provide and picking format too or it just give current date and time.
If question repeated please mention link

OR is there any other javascript to make a time and date picker

Comment: Why don't you look through the docs on their website to find out what momentjs does?

Comment: @83N i read there doc its a bit confusing in respect to picking of dates

Comment: momentjs is to "Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times" - it does not provide any sort of calendar control or date picker.  Your question isn't too clear so please can you provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to take two time 1st will be current another a future time with date to achieve a settime out functionality in my backend code

Comment: For the datepicker itself you'll have to find another library. You can use moment.js to display them in different formats, make easier calculations and conversions between times, and to normalize them for server usage

Comment: I got my answer :)

Comment: @casraf an you let me know which method actually moment have to calculate difference between two date+time combo

Comment: Check the docs for `subtract` to get the difference between 2 dates and you can use `format` and `duration` to decide how to display that difference

Answer (score 0):

okay I did it all to get **time-out functionality** in given time and date

this is app.js

```
  app.post('/aa', function (req, res, next) {   
  var first = req.body.firstd
  var second = req.body.secondd
  var firstt = moment(first)
  var secondds = moment(second)
  console.log(firstt)
  console.log(secondds)
  var timeoutto = secondds.diff(first)
  console.log(secondds.diff(first))

  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send('Hello world')
  }, timeoutto)
})
```

here is html

```
<form action="/aa" method="POST">
        <input type="datetime-local" name="firstd">
        <input type="datetime-local" name="secondd">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```